# VScode wont detect the Arduino library

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino

I am currently trying to control a servo from an Arduino for a laser turret through vscode. the problem is that vscode does not pick up on my library folder called <servo.h>. I have a folder named "workspace" with the servo library, the .ino file, and the workspace file for vscode.

Instead of platformIO, I'm using the Arduino extension for vscode. I'm using an Arduino UNO. here is the code so far:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo servo1;
Servo servo2;
int potval
int potpin = 0

void setup()
```

and here is what my c_cpp_properties.json file looks like:

```
{
    "configurations": [{
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "cStandard": "c17",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
    }],
    "version": 4
}
```

And I'm running Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

Although this topic is open for quite some time, a better solution could be as follows:

1. Check if the libraries you want to include are actually installed. You can use Library Manager of the Arduino IDE. This tool also helps you to update the libraries if new releases are available.
2. Ideally, you should know where these libraries actually are on your file system. On Windows, they might be located in the Arduino IDE installation folder or in your User directory. On a Mac, they are either in `/Users/<username>/Library/*` or `/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries/*`.
3. In order to properly use the includes in Visual Studio Code so that they are recognized, you can extend the array `includePath` in your `configurations` in the `c_cpp_properties.json` file. You can add the paths mentioned above.

In short, the result could look as follows:

```
{
"version": 4,
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Arduino",
        "includePath": [
             "/Your/first/added/library/",
             "/Your/second/added/library/with/subfolders/**",
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```

Afterwards, you can include the libraries as follows:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Servo.h>
    
// your code goes here
```

Comment: If c_cpp_properties.json is regenerated upon successful compile, how can any information in that file be used during compilation?

Comment: You are right, the c_cpp_properties.json is actually regenerated during compilation.
I have modified the includePath and forcedInclude and they will be set to the correct values afterwards.
I am not sure whether this needs to be done at least one time and if the settings are cached/stored somewhere else.

Answer (score -3):

Any local library file that is included must use `""` instead of `<>`.
`#include <Servo.h>`
should be replaced with
`#include "Servo.h"`
Here is a post describing the difference between the two:
[What is the difference between #include < filename > and #include “filename”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

Comment: If VScose is set up properly for Arduino, the angle brackets actually work. I use them all the time for external libraries.